# Proc tabulate grouping Data - Three variables

Tags: sas

I have three variable CONFIG, YEAR, TOT_SAL, i need all config in rows, years in columns and 
based on values in rows and columns i need sum of third variable TOT_SAL;

I am so far trying this;

```
 PROC TABULATE data=final OUT=work.final;
                CLASS CONFIG YEAR;
                TABLES CONFIG,YEAR;
                Var TOT_SAL;
                RUN;
```

This gives me cross tab for config and year but instead of frequency of config
i need SUM(TOT_SAL) in the cross tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do that. Since you didn't provide data I used the SASHELP.SHOES data set so this example can be replicated. If you need further assistance ensure to post actual sample data.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.shoes;
class region product;
var sales;
table region, product*(sales='')*(sum=''*f=dollar32.);
run;
```

The [first and second examples in the SAS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n18cg5nn785mrnn1semjee5eaywe.htm&locale=en) shows another method as well as explaining each step in detail.

The simplest answer is adding the VAR statement. Note that you have tot_sal in the CLASS statement. That is incorrect, because the CLASS statement is intended for categorical/grouping variables, not variables to be summarized. Those go in the VAR statement instead.

```
PROC TABULATE data=final OUT=work.final;
            CLASS CONFIG YEAR;
            VAR TOT_SAL;
            TABLES CONFIG, YEAR*TOTAL_SAL*(sum=''*f=dollar32.) ;

RUN;
```

Comment: Hi: i tried the second example and it is still providing me the same result, for variable TOT_SAL i need sum, where as in cross tab of CONFIG and YEAR i only receive values which are frequency of either of those.

Comment: Post your code otherwise I'm trying to guess at what you did and what went wrong.

Comment: I modified to the code that should work if your data is as described.

Comment: Code is running fine there is no error but the desired output is not received, for eg, there should be the sum of variable TOT_SAL in the cross tab however it is calculating the frequency of appearance in the data.

Comment: Well, without your code I'm going to have say you did it wrong but can't tell you what. The example above, first one, clearly works correctly so the method is correct. Either your data isn't in the correct structure or you missed part of the code.